# Как вывести текст на экран при помощи Python в macOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, macos

Мне нужно вывести определенный текст на экран. Например, вывести `Привет` в угол экрана в реальном времени. **Не на картинку**.

Я слышал, что это можно сделать через `Tkinter.label`, но не смог установить его на *macOS*:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

Может, есть какие-нибудь модули для этого или инструкции? [image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

**Первый вариант** - Если вы собираетесь использовать TKinter, то вам возможно потребуется делать окно приложения прозрачным, а после еще перехватывать нажатие мыши, чтобы пользователь смог пользоваться компьютером и далее. Это трудный вариант, по моему мнению.

**Второй вариант** - Использование языка программирования C++. Как пример: Desktop Goose, оттуда вы можете посмотреть примеры реализации (бегает утка по экрану, высвечивается различный текст)